# Python: Check if unique id exists in previous timestamp, if so, check timestamp before that (and so on)

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe, recursion

I have a giant table of data that looks like this.

```
ID    Name   Category   Discovery Date  Timestamp
1     Alpha    Low         3/1/2020      7/1/2020
1     Alpha    Low         4/7/2020      7/1/2020
1     Alpha    Low         5/2/2020      7/1/2020
2     Bravo    Medium      2/17/2020     7/1/2020
2     Bravo    Medium      2/26/2020     7/1/2020
3     Charlie  Low         6/1/2020      7/1/2020
1     Alpha    Low         5/2/2020      7/8/2020
2     Bravo    Medium      2/17/2020     7/8/2020
3     Charlie  Low         7/11/2020     7/15/2020
```

I am trying to insert a column between *Discovery Date* and *Timestamp* called *Target Date* that adds 90 days if *Category* == 'Low' and 30 days if *Category* == 'Medium' AND uses the earliest *Discovery Date* within a given *Timestamp* for all records with the same **ID**. However, a caveat is that if a specific **ID** was in the previous timestamp (current period - 1), I need to keep checking each previous timestamp until that **ID** does not show up in the previous timestamp, and then the earliest *Discovery Date* and *Category* logic can be used to determine the *Target Date*. Thus, the calculated field should look like this:

```
ID    Name   Category   Discovery Date     Target Date       Timestamp
1     Alpha    Low         3/1/2020         5/30/2020        7/1/2020  
1     Alpha    Low         4/7/2020         5/30/2020        7/1/2020  
1     Alpha    Low         5/2/2020         5/30/2020        7/1/2020  
2     Bravo    Medium      2/17/2020        3/18/2020        7/1/2020  
2     Bravo    Medium      2/26/2020        3/18/2020        7/1/2020  
3     Charlie  Low         6/1/2020         8/30/2020        7/1/2020  
1     Alpha    Low         5/2/2020         5/30/2020        7/8/2020   
2     Bravo    Medium      2/17/2020        3/18/2020        7/8/2020  
3     Charlie  Low         7/11/2020        10/9/2020        7/15/2020
```

I believe some sort of recursive function to start at the latest (in above example, 7/15/2020) *Timestamp* is needed to check if a specific **ID** is in previous timestamp. If that is satisfied, check previous timestamp for that **ID** and so on and so forth. Once logic fails, and **ID** is no longer in previous timestamp, then you can use the earliest *Discovery Date* and *Category* logic.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you were looking for? I thought it was easier to explain it by commenting the code, rather than writing a long explanation. BTW, the main idea is to identify contiguous timestamps for each ID and compute target dates based on them.

```py
import pandas as pd
import datetime
from functools import reduce, partial


# ### Create example Dataframe ### #
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[
        (1, 'Alpha', 'Low', '3/1/2020', '7/1/2020'),
        (1, 'Alpha', 'Low', '4/7/2020', '7/1/2020'),
        (1, 'Alpha', 'Low', '5/2/2020', '7/1/2020'),
        (2, 'Bravo', 'Medium', '2/17/2020', '7/1/2020'),
        (2, 'Bravo', 'Medium', '2/26/2020', '7/1/2020'),
        (3, 'Charlie', 'Low', '6/1/2020', '7/1/2020'),
        (1, 'Alpha', 'Low', '5/2/2020', '7/8/2020'),
        (2, 'Bravo', 'Medium', '2/17/2020', '7/8/2020'),
        (3, 'Charlie', 'Low', '7/11/2020', '7/15/2020'),
    ],
    columns=['ID', 'Name', 'Category', 'Discovery Date', 'Timestamp']
)
df['Discovery Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Discovery Date'])
df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'])
# ### Create example Dataframe ### #


# ### Support functions (skip for the moment, return here later) ### #
def get_contiguous_periods(periods):
    """Part a list sublist of elements whose difference is less than 2.
    So, in this case, find contiguous periods (a.k.a Timestamp) among those associated with a specific ID.

    Example: periods = [1,2,3,5] -> [[1,2,3], [5]]
    """
    p = sorted(periods)
    return reduce(
        lambda x, y: (x[:-1] + [x[-1] + [y]]) if (y - x[-1][-1] < 2)  else (x + [[y]]),
        p[1:],
        [[p[0]]],
    ) if len(p) else []

def get_earliest_date(id_periods, df=None):
    """Get the earliest date for each ID and Period"""
    return {
        tuple(k): df[(df.ID == id_periods['ID']) & (df.Period.isin(k))]['Discovery Date'].min()
        for k in id_periods['all_periods']
    }
# ### Support functions ### #

# The proposed solution is based on the idea of Period, i.e. a unique id associated to the Timestamp. 
# It identifies batches of data with the same Timestamp. We assume Period values temporally sorted, implying the 
# Timestamp column to be sorted (ascending); if it is not, you can easily sort the dataframe by Timestamp:
# df.sort_index(by=['Timestamp'], inplace=True)
# Compute the Period associated to each Timestamp
df['Period'] = df['Timestamp'].diff().dt.days.astype(bool).cumsum()

# Now start to compute the target date for each (ID, Period) pair.
# Define contiguous periods as sorted sequence of periods an ID appears in with a difference less than 2 from one to the next.
# e.g. [3, 4, 5]; [1, 2, 5] are NOT a contiguous periods
# Firstly, notice that contiguous periods will have the same earliest date, i.e. the minimum of Discovery Date in
# the corresponding samples.

# 1. Get all the periods an ID appears in
df_target_date = df.groupby(['ID'])['Period'].unique().reset_index(name='all_periods')

# 2. Compute contiguous periods for each ID
df_target_date['all_periods'] = df_target_date['all_periods'].map(get_contiguous_periods)
# 3. Get the earliest date for each pair (ID, contiguous periods)
df_target_date['all_periods'] = df_target_date.apply(partial(get_earliest_date, df=df), axis=1)

# 4. Create a Dataframe with the earliest date for each (ID, Period) pair.
# We name the earliest date as 'Target Date' only to ease the following tasks
df_target_date = pd.DataFrame(
    data=reduce(
        lambda x, y: x + reduce(
            lambda w, z: w + [([y.ID] + [l, z[1]]) for l in z[0]],
            sorted(y.all_periods.items()),
            [],
        ),
        df_target_date.itertuples(),
        []
    ),
    columns=['ID', 'Period', 'Target Date'],
)

# 5. Add earliest date to the original dataframe
df = df.merge(df_target_date, how='left', left_on=['ID', 'Period'], right_on=['ID', 'Period'])
# 6. Drop Period column
df.drop(columns=['Period'], inplace=True)

# 5. Compute the Target Date, following the rules based on the Category
df.loc[df.Category == 'Low', 'Target Date'] += datetime.timedelta(days=90)
df.loc[df.Category == 'Medium', 'Target Date'] += datetime.timedelta(days=30)

# Rearrange columns
df = df[['ID', 'Name', 'Category', 'Discovery Date', 'Target Date', 'Timestamp']]

# Print the result
print(df)
```

And this is the result

```sh
   ID     Name Category Discovery Date Target Date  Timestamp
0   1    Alpha      Low     2020-03-01  2020-05-30 2020-07-01
1   1    Alpha      Low     2020-04-07  2020-05-30 2020-07-01
2   1    Alpha      Low     2020-05-02  2020-05-30 2020-07-01
3   2    Bravo   Medium     2020-02-17  2020-03-18 2020-07-01
4   2    Bravo   Medium     2020-02-26  2020-03-18 2020-07-01
5   3  Charlie      Low     2020-06-01  2020-08-30 2020-07-01
6   1    Alpha      Low     2020-05-02  2020-05-30 2020-07-08
7   2    Bravo   Medium     2020-02-17  2020-03-18 2020-07-08
8   3  Charlie      Low     2020-07-11  2020-10-09 2020-07-15
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic isn't so easy to follow, but if I did, I think your answer on your last row result is incorrect as ID 3 is in two different timestamps. Anyway, you can play around with the logic as needed.

Each ID grouping only contains one category so I didn't test what would happen in the case where both categories were in the same ID, only tested what was presented.

Here's an approach you can try as it matches everything except the final row.

```
def add_time(x):
    lowtardate = x['DiscoveryDate'].iat[0] + timedelta(days=90)
    x.loc[x['Category']=='Low', 'TargetDate'] = lowtardate
    medtardate = x['DiscoveryDate'].iat[0] + timedelta(days=30)
    x.loc[x['Category']=='Medium', 'TargetDate'] = medtardate
    return x
df.groupby('ID').apply(add_time)
```

Output:

```
   ID     Name Category DiscoveryDate  Timestamp TargetDate
0   1    Alpha      Low    2020-03-01 2020-07-01 2020-05-30
1   1    Alpha      Low    2020-04-07 2020-07-01 2020-05-30
2   1    Alpha      Low    2020-05-02 2020-07-01 2020-05-30
3   2    Bravo   Medium    2020-02-17 2020-07-01 2020-03-18
4   2    Bravo   Medium    2020-02-26 2020-07-01 2020-03-18
5   3  Charlie      Low    2020-06-01 2020-07-01 2020-08-30
6   1    Alpha      Low    2020-05-02 2020-07-08 2020-05-30
7   2    Bravo   Medium    2020-02-17 2020-07-08 2020-03-18
8   3  Charlie      Low    2020-07-11 2020-07-15 2020-08-30
```